# Simple C# Translator

Tags: c#

Hi I am making a simple translator using c# and I have a list of English words. How can I make the program check the words that the user inputted and check them with the words in the list without making an if statement with a bunch of &&.

Any help please?

Comment: what did you tried until now ? Code Snippets needed.

Comment: maybe use [`RegEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Use a translate API on the web

Comment: Please be more specific. If you were to write these if statements, then what would they look like?

Comment: use a LINQ to loop in your collection with Words

Answer (score 3):

Use the Contains method of the List object.

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

1. Add all the words to a List
2. Check the list using the Contains() method

Answer (score 0):

Example: (sorry, it's @Stephane Mathis answer)

```
public static class SqlServerKeywords {
     public static readonly HashSet<string> SqlServerReservedKeywords = new HashSet<string> {
        "ADD",
        "EXISTS",
        "PRECISION",
        "ALL",
        "EXIT",
        "PRIMARY",
        "ALTER",
        "EXTERNAL",
        "PRINT",
        "AND",
        "FETCH",
        "PROC",
        "ANY",
        "FILE",
        "PROCEDURE",
        "AS",
        "FILLFACTOR",
        "PUBLIC",
        "ASC",
        "FOR"            
     };      
    }

public class OtherClass {             
     private bool Exists (string myWord) {            
        var exists = SqlServerReservedKeywords.Contains(myWord);
        return exists;
    }
}
```